# Was Leviticus 18:22 only prohibiting homosexuality that involved pagan rituals?

Tags: law, leviticus, torah, homosexuality

I have heard some progressive Christians claim that Leviticus 18:22 was only condemning homosexual activities for idolatrous rituals. I know that 1 Corinthians 6:9 and 1 Timothy 1:10 was using the word "arsenokoitai" which came from Leviticus 18:22 and Leviticus 20:13.

In Leviticus 18:2-3 it says:

> *“Speak to the people of Israel and say to them, I am the Lord your God. You shall not do as they do in the land of Egypt, where you lived, and you shall not do as they do in the land of Canaan, to which I am bringing you. You shall not walk in their statutes."*

There are some people who say that because of these verses, it was condemning the idolatrous practices in Egypt and Canaan which included homosexual sex. Therefore, in this context, it is only referring to homosexual activity that has idolatrous rituals involved. God was only prohibiting the rituals they did in Egypt and Canaan.

We also see in Leviticus 18:21, the verse before, it says:

> *"You shall not give any of your children to offer them to Molech, and so profane the name of your God: I am the Lord."*

Some have suggested that because of the context, Leviticus 18:22 is not prohibiting loving same-sex relationships but only ones that relate to pagan rituals. Is this true? If not, why?

Comment: Does Leviticus 18:21 *allow* the slaying of children *outside* of pagan worship ? If not, then why would the preceding verse *allow* for homosexual intercourse *outside* of pagan rituals ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let us be extremely clear about what Lev 18 is discussing which is explicitly stated in V3 -

> You must not follow the practices of the land of Egypt, where you used
> to live, and you must not follow the practices of the land of Canaan,
> into which I am bringing you. You must not walk in their customs.

Thus, the series of prohibitions concerning sexual practices all concern the pagan practices of Canaan.  The list of such prohibitions includes the following:

- incest generally (v6)
- sex with your mother (v7)
- sex with your step-mother (v8)
- sex with your sister of half-sister (v9)
- sex with your children or step-children (v10)
- sex with your half-siblings (v11)
- sex with your aunt (v12, 13) or aunt by marriage (v14)
- sex with your daughter-in-law (v15), sister-in-law(v16)
- sex with your daughter (v17) or step daughter or grand-daughter
- sex your sister-in-law (18)
- sex during menstrual bleeding (v19)
- sex with your neighbor's wife (v20)
- sex with another man (v22)
- sex with an animal (v23)

Now, whatever one claims about any one of these restrictions must be claimed about them all.  Thus if one claims (incorrectly) that v22 is only about ritual sex but does not apply to domestic sex, then one effectively claims that about all the other types of incest.

Thus, a claim that these prohibitions only apply during pagan rituals is to essentially say that all these types of incest are acceptable, including what is now known as pedophilia!!.  In the words of Rom 3:8, "***Those who say such things deserve to be condemned***."

The sexual prohibitions were to serve Israel well by keeping them free of the sexual practices in the surrounding pagan culture.  Paul repeats these prohibitions in Rom 1:26, 27.

Comment: As long as it happened within the bounds of marriage, I doubt they'd had much problems with pedophilia.  They had no age of consent and marriage was about joining families (not love) - if there only were children available to forge such an alliance, children would be married off.  Incest however was something else.

Comment: Where is pedophilia mentioned?  Having sex with one's own **adult** son or daughter is not pedophilia, but still taboo in many if not (virtually) all cultures.

Comment: @gerrit v22 prohibits sex between a man and a male (zakar), forbidding both general homosexual acts and pedastry. That's not a general prohibition, though.

Comment: -1 The logic here does not follow.  Interpreting this particular Scripture as not forbidding those things would not therefore mean that those things are allowed. It can always be forbidden in other parts of Scripture. They can also not be allowed based on Scriptural principles that don't directly mention the specific case. (For example, Jesus says that we are not to harm children. We know child sexual abuse harms children, therefore child sexual abuse is not allowed.)

Comment: @trlkly He doesn't say that; rather, he continues the reasoning of folks who say it is only permissible in the case of pagan ritual. If one (wrongly) postulates that this verse implies that homosexual acts are permissible outside of pagan acts, then he makes the case that this reasoning would hold for every command in the unit, thus meaning that incest and adultery outside of ritual acts are permissible, a contradiction.

Comment: While I like some content of this answer, I must agree with @trlkly. A good answer to *Is it forbidden specifically here?* is not *if it's not, then look at all these horrible things that are also not completely forbidden anymore by this exact verse!*, it's an explicit and based yes or no.

Comment: @JohnDumancic this has been so convoluted I don’t even know if you are making sense, though you are... I think

Comment: @JohnDumancic The Answer flat out says otherwise: "Thus, a claim that these prohibitions only apply during pagan rituals is to essentially say that all these types of incest are acceptable, including what is now known as pedophilia!!"

Comment: @JohnDumancic I also note that I have never seen anyone claim that these behaviors are permissible because of these Scriptures. They are argue that the Bible as a whole doesn't forbid it, going after both context and translation of multiple Scriptures. They then usually also appeal to the nature of God and argue the prohibition goes against that. (I personally also add Romans 14:1.)

Comment: v18 has always interested me (and probably Onan too).  Did these rules not apply back in Genesis?

Comment: @mcalex - they clearly did not apply to Abraham who married his half-sister.  They also did not apply to Adam and Eve's children who married their siblings.

Comment: If all these must be treated equally, does that mean that in the eyes of god having sex with a woman on her period is morally equivalent to having sex with your child?

Comment: @QuadmasterXLII - Great question and one that deserves its own separate question.

Comment: @Dottard - v11 didn't necessarily cover Abraham's situation, since it only applies if the half sister grew up with you. The disfunctional relationship between Jacob Rachel & Leah, is possibly the reason behind v18.

Comment: @Quadmaster v19 only applies if you uncover a woman's nakedness during her menstruation. But if you are already married to the woman, her nakedness is your nakedness (v7-8). You aren't uncovering anything. I think the idea is that people were approaching women on their periods to have sex out of wedlock without producing a child out wedlock. Notice the difference in consequences for menstrual sex when uncovering nakedness (20:18) and when not uncovering nakedness (15:24).

Answer (score 18):

What isn't addressed in other answers is where the claim comes from. Without understanding the claim, they fail to counter it. In particular, they all rely on the common English versions of the verses, where the claim arises from analysis of the original Hebrew.

And one of the complications is that nearly every English translation adds a key word that may be substantially changing the reading of the verse. As per enegue's answer, the common translation is something like "You shall not lie with a male **as** with a woman; it is an abomination." - but the word "as" is an English addition. A literal translation of the Hebrew reads something like this:

> With (a) male you shall not lie (the) lyings of a woman. (An) abomination is that.

[Source](https://blog.smu.edu/ot8317/2019/04/11/lost-in-translation-alternative-meaning-in-leviticus-1822/)

This does not fully capture the meaning, of course, but it demonstrates the issue. Without that joining word, "as", it could just as easily be read as "lying with a man is wrong in the same way as lying with a woman"... which has led [some](https://blog.smu.edu/ot8317/2016/05/11/leviticus-1822/) to suggest that it's extending the previous rules against incest to apply equally to male relatives, something like "Sexual intercourse with a close male relative should be just as abominable to you as incestuous relationships with female relatives" (as a paraphrase, not a translation).

To make matters more complex, the context must also be accounted for. As you have noted, the verse immediately before it has nothing to do with sex - instead, it has to do with sacrifice of children to Moloch. Its presence in the middle of a list that seems otherwise to be a list of sexual acts that are forbidden is curious, and any valid interpretation must account for this. If the intent was to rule out things that Canaanites were doing, you would think that sacrifices to Moloch would come either before or after sexual prohibitions, not in the middle.

Moloch was, according to some interpretations, a fertility god. It is not unusual for pagan fertility rituals to involve sex and sacrifice of children. There is also good reason to think that bestiality would fall into the same category, given that Moloch was represented as a man-bull hybrid. It has therefore been proposed by [some](https://www.stopbibleabuse.org/biblical-references/leviticus.html) that the verse (and all of the others in the same chapter) is referring to ritual sexual acts.

Another observation that has been made is that the verse does not use the Hebrew word for Man, but the word for Male. This is unusual, and while it could be read as an intent to separate "adult women" from "girls" but applying the prohibition to all men and boys, it is still an unusual choice of wording. More notably, it doesn't prohibit boys sleeping with boys, only men sleeping with males. What's interesting about this is that, at least according to some, in Greek culture at the time, pederasty was quite common... but they would refer to it as "men sleeping with males" (in Greek). The parallel is certainly suggestive; whether it's meaningful or not is certainly up for debate. This theory has also been [suggested](https://blog.smu.edu/ot8317/2016/05/11/leviticus-1822/).

To specifically address something said by Dottard - the fact that Leviticus 18 (and Leviticus 20) may only apply to some subset need not mean that all other cases are acceptable. To assume otherwise is to assume that incest with your niece is acceptable, as it is not included in the extensive list provided in Leviticus. More specifically, Deuteronomy provides a much more restricted list of incest that are prohibited.

What's more, contrary to Dottard's assertion, there is nothing in the Bible addressing paedophilia, directly or indirectly. Nothing in Leviticus, or Deuteronomy, or other books establishes any form of paedophilia as an abomination. Interpreting Leviticus 18 to refer to ritual acts doesn't change this in any way. Meanwhile, Deuteronomy and Exodus both address bestiality.

The final piece of evidence for why Leviticus 18 (and 20) might not be referring to general sexual activity is that, despite incest being clearly marked as bad in these chapters, some very important people in the bible committed what we would now call incest, including Abraham and Sarah (who was either Abraham's half-sister or niece).

Of course, there are counterarguments to all of this, too. The truth is not as clear-cut as the English translations would have you believe.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122929/discussion-on-answer-by-glen-o-was-leviticus-1822-only-prohibiting-homosexualit).

Comment: "To assume otherwise is to assume that incest with your niece is acceptable..." Do you have any reason to assume that marrying one's niece in indeed prohibited? I know that classic Jewish law permits marrying a niece (though not an aunt marrying a nephew). I didn't know that any group does prohibit it on based on biblical law.

Comment: @Binyomin - I wasn't asserting that it's acceptable or prohibited, but pointing out that the failure for it to be mentioned specifically in this listing does not automatically mean it's acceptable. It wasn't intended as a general statement, but as a counterpoint to Dottard's assertion that reading this specific chapter as only prohibiting ritual incest means all other incest must be acceptable.

Answer (score 9):

The OP has only given half the context. Verses 3 and 4 spell it out completely:

> *<sup>3</sup>**You shall not do as they do in the land of Egypt**, where you lived, and **you shall not do as they do in the land of Canaan**, to which I am bringing you. **You shall not walk in their statutes**. <sup>4</sup>**You shall follow my rules and keep my statutes and walk in them.** I am the LORD your God.*
> <sub>`Leviticus 18:3-4 (ESV)`</sub>

And God clearly spells out HIS rule concerning same sex union:

> *<sup>22</sup>You shall not lie with a male as with a woman; it is an abomination.*
> <sub>`Leviticus 18:22 (ESV)`</sub>

If one truly wishes to seek to please the LORD God, then they will seek to obey and advertise HIS rules, not the rules of those who dwell around them.

Answer (score 3):

The abhorrent abominable sin of sodomy named after the Sodomites who practiced sodomy was not restricted to religious activities.

#### Definition

> sexual intercourse involving anal or oral copulation

This means that sodomy is NOT limited to homosexuals but like in the case of Lot’s daughters, they were offered to the mob to be sodomized. Hence a heterosexual extramarital act but sodomy none the less.

Lot’s visitors were in Lot’s house and yet the residents of Sodom were interested in sodomizing them in a non ceremonious manner, non religious, non temple-like context.

> “Behold, this was the guilt of your sister Sodom: she and her daughters had pride, excess of food, and prosperous ease, but did not aid the poor and needy. **They were haughty and did an abomination before me**. So I removed them, when I saw it.”
> ‭‭Ezekiel‬ ‭16:49-50‬ ‭

> “But in the prophets of Jerusalem I have seen a horrible thing: they commit adultery and walk in lies; they strengthen the hands of evildoers, so that no one turns from his evil; all of them have become like Sodom to me, and its inhabitants like Gomorrah.””
> Jeremiah‬ ‭23:14‬ ‭

> “For the look on their faces bears witness against them; they proclaim their sin like Sodom; **they do not hide it**. Woe to them! For they have brought evil on themselves.”
> ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭3:9‬ ‭

The people of Sodom were not involved in pagan rituals, they were burning in lust for Lot’s visitors.

> “And they called to Lot, “Where are the men who came to you tonight? Bring them out to us, that we may **know** them.”

In what manner were they asking to know the men?

> Behold, I have two daughters **who have not known any man**. Let me bring them out to you, and do to them as you please. Only do nothing to these men, for they have come under the shelter of my roof.””
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭19:5, 8‬ ‭

It is obvious sexually and as per Isaiah 3:9. It was out in the open, it was not a religious act, not a pagan ritual.

#### Summary

It is sodomy that God sees as an abomination and a sin. Therefore since homosexuals can practically only practice sodomy sexually, they can’t have regular coitus, homosexuality is a sin as it’s sodomy based.

Furthermore given heterosexuals can also practice sodomy, heterosexual, consensual sodomy even in the context of a monogamous marriage is still an abomination and a sin.

Comment: Downvoted for "sodomy". The sin of Sodom was rape and abuse of hospitality, not homosexuality.

Comment: @nick012000 *“You shall not lie with a male as with a woman; it is an abomination.”
‭‭Lev18:22‬* the MEN of Sodom wanted to rape the MEN visiting Lot and according to you God was only upset about the rape part and being inhospitable. *“If a man lies with a male as with a woman, both of them have committed an abomination; they shall surely be put to death; their blood is upon them.”
‭‭Lev20:13‬ “just as Sodom and the surrounding cities, which likewise indulged in sexual immorality and pursued **unnatural desire**, serve as an example by undergoing a punishment of eternal fire”
‭‭Jude‬ ‭1:7‬*

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Compare it to the story of the Levite's concubine, where the same thing happened and it's clear that it's the violence and lack of hospitality are the primary sins being condemned. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levite%27s_concubine Additionally, this is official doctrine by some Christian denominations, like the Anglicans.

Comment: @nick012000. *“And the man, the master of the house, went out to them and said to them, “No, my brothers, do **not act so wickedly**; since this man has come into my house, **do not do this vile thing**. Behold, here are my virgin daughter and his concubine. Let me bring them out now. **Violate them** and do with them what seems good to you, but **against this man do not do this OUTRAGEOUS thing**.””*
‭‭Judges‬ ‭19:23-24‬ ‭by your logic it was lack of hospitality (yet the man was received well) rape was the issue, but it was okay to sodomize the women? You have no leg to stand on.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo The "outrageous thing" in question was the rape of people given the rights of hospitality, and it would have been just as bad if the angels were women, yes. He then offered his daughter and concubine to appease the crowd, and while it was still bad, they weren't guests so their rape wasn't as bad as the rape of the angels would have been - it was rape alone, rather than rape *and* the violation of hospitality.

Comment: @nick012000 when you can show it in the text you’ll have something to go by until then it’s your opinionated interpretation and it doesn’t have historical backing either

Comment: @NihilSineDeo See my link to the Wikipedia page discussing the parallel story about the Levite's concubine, where it's explicitly the violence that's condemned, not the homosexuality. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levite%27s_concubine

Comment: @nick012000 when YOU can show your claim in the Scripture then you’ll have something to go by, until then it’s just opinionated interpretation and it doesn’t have history backing either

Comment: @NihilSineDeo The verse doesn't say how onboard with the plan the daughters were, but at the time the daughters would've been expected to do what their father instructed them to do without question. As such, if the men had taken Lot up on his offer, the daughters would have consented as they were instructed, and therefore it would not have been considered rape (at the time). It can even be argued that rape itself qualifies as unnatural desire as you are taking someone against their will and free will is one of God's greatest gifts.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo Sodomy means what it means, whether or not you think it's the main sin of Sodom. NihilSineDeo used the term accurately.

Comment: I'm not going to address the hermeneutics of this, but I think there are some logic problems here.  The answer starts with "definition", followed by *a* definition (source not named) of the English word "sodomy", and a definition that I would argue doesn't agree with the bulk of modern usage, which would restrict it to anal sex.  In any case, that's begging the question and tells us nothing what was meant by "the sin of sodom" given that the Bible was not written in English.  I don't think this paragraph is well-justified or useful.

Comment: And the penultimate paragraph is, well, peculiar at best.  "Homosexuality is sodomy based"?  I think this reflects a fundamental lack of knowledge about the reality of homosexual men.  And utterly ignores the fact that most lesbians are extremely unlikely to do anything that could be classed as sodomy.  I think it's best to stick to the textual stuff, rather than extend into theories about sexual practices unless you can cite evidence about them.

Comment: @tea-and-cake fortunately for you the author of the Scriptures, is not dead but can be consulted about any and every passage. Considering the practical implication of deliverance from addictions brought on by sodomite unclean spirits results in permanent release when sodomy is defined correct and denounced, I’ll stick to what works based on what was revealed. Until then you can continue telling yourself (or being told) what you want to hear.  *“Let the evildoer still do evil, and the filthy still be filthy, and the righteous still do right, and the holy still be holy*.””
‭‭Revelation‬ ‭22:11‬

Comment: This is the Biblical Hermeneutics stack, not Christianity.  Justified claims are supposed to be the order of the day.  In your original answer you mostly did quite well to cite biblical passages.  I have pointed out a few flaws in your logic which you could respond to in order to improve your answer.  But your response is an incoherent and ungrammatical rant (plus some assumptions about my motivations).  It's a shame you reject the invitation to communicate more clearly, but you are quite correct that your opinions are of no interest to me.

Answer (score 2):

In [The "Lyings" of a Woman: Male-Male Incest in Leviticus 18.22?](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1558/tse.v15i2.231), a philological/literary analysis of Lev 18.22:

> If the text is analysed and translated carefully, there are reasons to believe that Lev. 18.22 is proscribing incest between male family members.

the paper argues the original meaning was, while hard to translate, something akin to

> (a) You shall not lie with close relatives, whether male or female.
> (b) With a male relative you shall not engage in sexual relationships
> prohibited with female relatives.

Answer (score 1):

There are argumentations that support the sense that this prohibition is to be seen in the context of Canaanite practice, probably first discussed by [John E. Hartley](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1074996.Leviticus).

An exhaustive discussion supporting this theses is published by [Luis Quinones-Roman](https://www.academia.edu/35653542/THE_PROHIBITION_AGAINST_CERTAIN_SEXUAL_PRACTICES_HOMOSEXUALITY_IN_THE_HOLINESS_CODE_LEVITICUS_18_22_and_20_13), I cite

> If indeed v. 21 referred to the practice of temple prostitution among
> the Canaanites; then the assumption  is  to  say  that  v.  22
> outlawssuch  temple  prostitution.  This  might  be  suggesting  that
> if homosexual  intercourse  is  performed  within  the  parameters  of
> temple  prostitution  then  is  an abomination  because  YHWH  cannot
> cohabit  among  other  gods  or  forms  of  worships—there  is  no
> documented  evidence  whether  the  Israelites  were  practicing  or
> not  temple  prostitution — as  the  final clause in v. 21 reads. For
> Grünwaldt* these two verses of the Law are the only legal sentences in
> the Old Testament that prohibit non-cultic homosexuality.

Is this true?

There is no evidence that in ancient times Lev. 18:22 has ever been interpreted in the sense that it refers only to homosexual practise in Canaanite cult.

*Klaus Grünwaldt, 1999, p. 192